# How to make VSCode hightlight JS string as CSS selector?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a lot of ts/js-files with objects which props contains CSS selectors. Is there any way to add CSS-selector-hightlight to the strings in VSCode?

Every of this strings has defined TypeScript type in the parent class.

Comment: related but not exactly a dup since it's about whole rules and not just selectors: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75399730/11107541