# JavaScript Injector optimization

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I have ability and task to inject html into a page
also I do have large url encoded html page that should be injected in a specific point in a webPage
to implement it I'm using js injector
basically I'm just injecting injector that places and decodes html into specific div

Injector should output just html text
my version

```js
function inject(content) {
    return `
    <script id='injectionPoint'>
    function getClosestForm(inputElement) {
        let parent = inputElement.parentElement;
        while (parent != null) {
            if (parent.nodeName === 'FORM') {
                return parent;
            }
            parent = parent.parentElement;
        }
        return null;
    }
    const elements = getClosestForm(document.getElementById('injectionPoint')).querySelectorAll('div.field-group');
    let lastElement = document.getElementById("injectionPoint");
    let node = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(decodeURIComponent(\`${content}\`));
    lastElement.parentElement.insertBefore(node, lastElement.nextSibling)
    </script>
    `
}
```

the problem with this approach is, I dont have any highlight in vscode
any ways to make it more editable like a code instead of text)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I propose to close as dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/75399730/11107541 (once it qualifies)

Comment: Yeah sure, but you are certain that `content` is not just some arbitrary user content, right? Because this is literally injecting whatever script a user would want to run otherwise.  It also seems better to just run the script instead, instead of kind-of-evalling it on the fly with an injected script...